# SQLite: Create multiple indexes , multiple index columns vs single index which one will help to get the best performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, sqlite, indexing

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `ng1` (
    `word1` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `kd`    TEXT NOT NULL,
    `kd1`   TEXT NOT NULL,
    `kd2`   TEXT,
    `kd3`   TEXT,
    `dt`    INTEGER DEFAULT '0',
    `dm`    INTEGER DEFAULT '0',
    `freq`  REAL DEFAULT '0',
    `lastused`  INTEGER DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY(word1)
);
```

And i have these types of queries:

```
SELECT * FROM ng1 WHERE kd='abc' ORDER BY freq DESC
SELECT * FROM ng1 WHERE kd1='a' AND dt='1' ORDER BY freq DESC
SELECT * FROM ng1 WHERE kd2='ab' AND dt='1' AND dm='1' ORDER BY freq DESC
SELECT * FROM ng1 WHERE kd3='abc' AND dt='1' AND dm='1' ORDER BY freq DESC
SELECT * FROM ng1 WHERE kd3='abc' AND word1 LIKE 'abc%' AND dt='1' AND dm='1' ORDER BY freq DESC
```

So what kind of index will help me get the best performance?

1. Create multiple indexes for every single field i need to use in query - - index1: kd

   - index2: kd1
   - index3: kd2 .... and indexes with for kd3,dt,dm,freq field
2. Create multiple indexes with multiple columns:

   - index1: kd,freq
   - index2: kd1,freq
   - index3: kd2,freq
   - index4: kd3,freq
   - index5: kd3,dt,dm,freq
3. Create single index with multiple columns:

   - index1: kd,kd1,kd2,kd3,dt,dm,freq

Comment: That depends. What did you measure?

Comment: @CL. it depends on what?

Comment: On the actual data, and your hardware, and software. Again, what did you measure?

Comment: I gave you the db structure, and what i want is to find the best index way to archive the best performance. if i've done the measuring, i don't have to ask which index way is the best.

Comment: The DB structure is not enough (otherwise, [ANAYLZE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) would not exist). Answering this would require [more explanations](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html) that appropriate on SO.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

These comments apply to MySQL.

First of all, you **cannot index `TEXT`**.  You can index `VARCHAR` up to some limit (usually 255).  So, where practical, change `TEXT` to some reasonable length `VARCHAR(n)`.

**Let's look at your examples**:

```
SELECT * FROM ng1 WHERE kd='abc' ORDER BY freq DESC
SELECT * FROM ng1 WHERE kd1='a' AND dt='1' ORDER BY freq DESC
SELECT * FROM ng1 WHERE kd2='ab' AND dt='1' AND dm='1' ORDER BY freq DESC
SELECT * FROM ng1 WHERE kd3='abc' AND dt='1' AND dm='1' ORDER BY freq DESC
```

Those four are essentially all the same:  The `WHERE` has only '=' AND'd together.  So start a composite index with those variables in any order.  Since you finished the `WHERE` and did not have a `GROUP BY`, you can move on to the `ORDER BY`.  Add `freq` to the end.  The last one, for example, needs

```
INDEX(kd3, dt, dm, freq) or
INDEX(dm, dt, kd4, freq) or ...
```

This case is different because of the **`LIKE`**:

```
SELECT * FROM ng1 WHERE kd3='abc' AND word1 LIKE 'abc%' AND dt='1' AND dm='1' ORDER BY freq DESC
```

The `LIKE` without a leading wildcard is considered a "range", sort of like `word1 >= 'abc' AND word1 < 'abd'`.  As with `ORDER BY`, a range will be the *last* column used in an index.  So, the best you can do is:

```
INDEX(kd3, dt, dm, word1)
```

The first 3 can be in any order, but `word1` must come *after* them.  Adding `freq` will be of no use.

I discuss this and more in my [Index Cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

So, in your example, 5 different indexes for the 5 `SELECTs` is optimal.  If, for whatever reason, you wanted to minimize the number of indexes, here are two approaches:

Sometimes the optimizer will be happy with skipping the `WHERE` and using an **index for the `ORDER BY`**.  In that case `INDEX(freq)` would be "better than nothing" for all 5.

Your question suggested some "consolidating".  I would suggest `INDEX(dt, dm, kd3)`, in exactly that order, would handle the last 4 `SELECTs` "better than nothing".  `dt` has to be first for #2.  `kd3` was added because it helps #4 and #5.

Other notes...

**`NULL`/`NOT NULL`** does not matter much.

**`PRIMARY KEY(word1)`** is "better than nothing", but only for #5.  And, depending on cardinality, it *might* be used in preference over the one I suggested.

**Write operations** (`INSERT`, `DELETE`, and sometimes `UPDATE`) are slowed down by having lots of indexes.  However, usually the benefit to the `SELECTs` outweighs this.  So, as long as you don't "index every column", don't worry about the number of indexes.

Comment: In SQLite, there is no varchar field, and i've tried to index text field in SQLite and it works, it runs faster than without index. So the answer is creating every single particular index for each query with multiple columns?

Comment: It would create too much indexes. Anyway to used to it with less index field? For example: `SELECT * FROM ng1 WHERE kd1='a' AND dt=any AND dm = any ?`

Comment: Any index _starting_ with kd1 may help that query.  That is, even `INDEX(kd1)` may be worth having.  There is a tradeoff between having the 'best' indexes versus having 'too many' indexes.  And 'caching' comes into play -- perhaps that is why it _happened_ to run faster _that time_ without the index.